# In TypeScript, How to define type for Class that has a static method as arguments?

Tags: typescript

```
class MyNumber {
  private __value: number;

  static from(value: any): MyNumber | null {
    if (typeof value === 'number') {
      return new MyNumber(value);
    }
    return null;
  }

  constructor(value: number) {
    this.__value = value;
  }

  to(): any {
    return { type: 'NUMBER', value: this.__value };
  }
}

class MyString {
  private __value: string;

  static from(value: any): MyString | null {
    if (typeof value === 'string') {
      return new MyString(value);
    }
    return null;
  }

  constructor(value: string) {
    this.__value = value;
  }

  to(): any {
    return { type: 'STRING', value: this.__value };
  }
}

class MyBoolean {
  private __value: boolean;

  static from(value: any): MyBoolean | null {
    if (typeof value === 'boolean') {
      return new MyBoolean(value);
    }
    return null;
  }

  constructor(value: boolean) {
    this.__value = value;
  }

  to(): any {
    return { type: 'BOOLEAN', value: this.__value };
  }
}
```

I want to define a type so that only classes of a specific form are accepted as arguments.

Please tell me what type should for `Klass` be defined in the code below.

```
function func(Klass, value: any): any {
  const instance = Klass.from(value);
  return instance ? instance.to() : null;
}

const output = hello(MyNumber, 3);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The minimum viable typing given the implementation of `func()` would be this:

```
function func(Klass: { from(value: any): null | { to(): any } }, value: any): any {
  const instance = Klass.from(value);
  return instance ? instance.to() : null;
}
```

You could rewrite that with interfaces if you want, but it's the same thing:

```
interface Toable {
  to(): any;
}
interface Fromable {
  from(value: any): Toable | null;
}    
function func(Klass: Fromable, value: any): any {
  const instance = Klass.from(value);
  return instance ? instance.to() : null;
}
```

The only information about `Klass` that you're using is that it has a method named `from()` which takes `any` parameter and returns either `null` or a new object with a `to()` method taking no parameters and returning `any`.  That allows your example code to work:

```
const output = func(MyNumber, 3);
const output2 = func(MyString, 1); // accepts any, doesn't it?
const output3 = func(MyBoolean, 100);
```

But balks at arguments without a proper `from()` method:

```
const bad = func(Date, 10); // error
// ------------> ~~~~
// Property 'from' is missing in type 'DateConstructor' but required in type 'Fromable'

const alsoBad = func({ from() { return "oopsie" } }, 123); // error
// ------------------> ~~~~
// Type 'string' is not assignable to type 'Toable | null'
```

And it doesn't care if the argument is necessarily a constructor, since it doesn't use it to construct anything with `new`:

```
const okay = func({ from() { return null } }, 345); // okay
const output = func(MyNumber, 3);
```

So that all looks good.  As an aside I'd suggest avoiding `any` types unless you can't write something more descriptive.  But you didn't ask that, so I'll stop here. Hope that helps; good luck!

[Playground link to code](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/#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-QDoAAMQzUDwObdFM1hKClmAtDGGLUUfUqGRkB4RpKBqWQyOAJQAGlwCgbgUMUfCbizbE91WZsJ3EGxJw0RCJgYn4hkw3tpkPfiUXIxgAH5pIkWShj1aB2hHL9Kl4uhoHkZA6DIfT11I8ilD0FJsBuABmPsiG03T9MMugACZjJosz4C5fEbgARiyaAAHoAuWYBALIOgYBWG4ABN5EwCAeB8HTKDoOSvklHS9IM-SrLc0zO3jQtfIABmK2z0snaB0DAaK8togARKMSv8oLoBwBRsGIVqAFper6-reoAPmgAA-MaRq64KAAUFGcbBHF8TCfBsGBUEGCB8X4s1GB8RqGAAYQy+pGmaZb0CMiIAEdkEoCJaoRbbfBY1B8J8LSMuWEAIHkY4arqpRTXErpWyHaAACIgzIDbMDBmYZl85ybMEQLgva5pJugAasex4bxomohWqtXZfAZYFlsGXh5B0n5KGBHh8N6eRHp8PCwIIkUQDe7d7PkABrMBVgmEzaMBjNFm2KSiTh3JrIAFgAVha4K+YFoA)